# Can't import audiolab in python

Tags: python, audio-processing

I installed audiolab from this source:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.audiolab

Those are the only windows binaries for python 2.7 I was able to find.

When I call `from scikits import audiolab` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from scikits import audiolab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pysndfile.matapi import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\pysndfile\matapi.py", line 145, in <module>
    Format('wav', 'pcm16').file_format)
  File "_sndfile.pyx", line 170, in scikits.audiolab.pysndfile._sndfile.Format.__init__ (scikits\audiolab\pysndfile\_sndfile.c:1429)
NameError: _SNDFILE_FILE_FORMAT
```

Is there a way to fix it? If not what should I use for audio processing instead? (Audiolab seemed to be the best alternative among audiotools and pyaudio)

EDIT:

After replacing libsndfile-1.dll, I have this new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from scikits import audiolab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pysndfile import formatinfo, sndfile
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\pysndfile\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _sndfile import Sndfile, Format, available_file_formats, \
  File "numpy.pxd", line 30, in scikits.audiolab.pysndfile._sndfile (scikits\audiolab\pysndfile\_sndfile.c:9632)
ValueError: numpy.dtype does not appear to be the correct type object
```

Note: numpy is installed.

Comment: I have same problem with `numpy.dtype` on Mac OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you need to install [libsndfile-1.0.25](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) as is mentioned right where you downloaded the binary

> Scikits.audiolab is a package for audio file IO using numpy arrays. Linked against libsndfile-1.0.25.

You can download an installer from [here](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/#Download). You may need to reinstall the `scikits.audiolab` distribution after you install `libsndfile` (although honestly, I'm not sure).

However, if this seems a lot of effort, it might be easier for you to install Python 2.6 and install `audiolab` from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.audiolab/) as [scikits docs](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/installing.html) suggest. The `PyPi` version of `scikits.audiolab` is statically linked to `libsndfile` so you will not need to install it on your own.

Comment: Well, the libsndfile is already included in my version (and I also installed libsndfile to make sure). The PyPi version is for Python 2.6 only...

Comment: Which version of libsndfile should you install, 32-bit or 64-bit?  Does it depend on the bit depth of your Python installation or your computer or you OS?

Comment: Also this doesn't fix my installation.  It used to work, but now it gives this error.  `File "_sndfile.pyx", line 170, in scikits.audiolab.pysndfile._sndfile.Format.__init__ (scikits\audiolab\pysndfile\_sndfile.c:1429)
NameError: _SNDFILE_FILE_FORMAT`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac OS. It's possible that you updated or installed a new version of python/numpy after you install audiolab. What I did is uninstall scikits.audiolab and reinstall it again, which got rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.  The reason was that the installed version of audiolab was for python2.5, but in the meantime with Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS python was upgradee to version 2.6.  After a new install of audiolab (wich grabbed the correct version) all's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to install libsndfile would have worked also.

```
brew install libsndfile
```