# Any convenient way to do live audio processing in Python?

Tags: python, audio

I'm desperately seeking for a way to do live audio processing (real time) under Python. It can also be Cython or any other way that makes this possible.

Ideally, I'd like to have simple audio in-out app that reads sound sample from sound card and puts it on sound output. Then I can add processing steps in between.

I have found several entries on this matter, but could easily install tools that are needed. For instance, there is a great blog entry for live audio processing with Cython&Python, but one needs PyAudio, but I get error and could find any fix to that...
[Can't import audiolab in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186674/cant-import-audiolab-in-python/15689920#15689920)

Thanks in advance for your help,

regards,
Bulek.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pysnack](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/). Using Snack you can create powerful multi-platform audio applications with just a few lines of code. Snack has commands for basic sound handling, such as playback, recording, file and socket I/O.